# Merge last n number of commits from perforce repository to git repository

Tags: git, migration, perforce, git-p4

we have migrated our code base from perforce to git. development going on both perforce and git repository. Now I want to merge latest n number of commits from perforce to git repository. How to do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can' t just merge the last X number of commits because a merge commit is about merging the _history_ of 2 branches.... you would need to rewrite (with a `rebase`, probably)  those commits you want to merge on top of the upstream branch, then you could try merging on top of the upstream (in case you do not want to do a fast-forward of the upstream).

Comment: Okay, but is there any way to sync all latest changes in perforce repository with git repository. Because we are in the middle of migration phase and some development is still going on in perforce repository.